# Adjust grep command to avoid 'extra' lines

Tags: grep, cygwin-x

I have to find some text inside zipped files. I am using Cygwin.
Some zipped files are empty. 
Obviously I don't want to have 'noisy' information about those 'empty zip files' at all.
E.g.

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -print -exec unzip -l {} \; |grep -i vbs
```

Where `vbs` is a string I'm searching for.

The problem is that it returns what I'm looking for but it also returns a lot of noise with lines like this:

```
C\ProgramData\ABC\DEF\VBScripts\OutputArchiveFiles.vbs
warning [/z/XYZ/Backup/123/456/Backup Set 1/Backup Files 1/Backup files 2.zip]:  zipfile is empty
```

I don't want to see those lines with 'zipfile is empty'

I tried to pipe it with `|grep -v 'zipfile is empty'` but it still outputs those lines as well.

My question: how can I avoid printing those 'empty' lines and see only the lines I'm looking for; i.e., vbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those additional lines are probably in the `stderr` stream. You could test by seeing if they [redirect out to a separate file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/for-cygwin-how-do-i-export-the-output-in-a-terminal-into-a-file) (e.g. `command 2> error.txt`)

Basically, run:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -print -exec unzip -l {} \; 2> error.txt |grep -i vbs
```

If this fixes your problem, you can replace `error.txt` with `/dev/null` (this may not work on all versions of cygwin)

Comment: Thanks for reply but redirecting to 2> did not make any difference i.e. file error.txt get created, it's empty and I still have printed a lot of 'empty' lines, Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: - Jedi, thanks so much, Not it works perfect. The last one request: current implementation find . -iname '*.zip' -print -exec unzip -l {} \; 2> error.txt |grep -i vbs    ... will match pattern in the file name. BUT in most cases I need to find file based on the content e.g. vbs is not a part of the file name but part of the file content. Could you help me i.e. enable to search based on file content. Thanks again and appreciate your help